# If Websocket does a lot of works, should i create another WebSocket?

Tags: reactjs, redux, websocket

If Websocket does a lot of works, should i create another WebSocket?

I'm using Websocket in my react application. To simply explain about my app, when user enters classroom page, then make object of Websocket and update socket information in reducer.

When WebSocket connected, teachers can connect to student's computer so they have access of remote control and they can chat each others. I have question here, i believe that the Websocket has too many functions to do, so i tried to make another Websocket for chatting function. Therefore, one socket is for remote control and the other is for chat.

Is it right way to make another Websocket in reducer? Or is there any other suggestions?

Comment: Not sure if you go down this way. Just directly connecting a client to client via websocket is not a good practice and it would lead to security issues. Always have a server in between and then pass things only which you have programmed for. Infact one of the very old hacks when yahoo chats was there is that during file share, it made a direct connection between machines and it lead to many accounts and systems compromised.

Comment: single websocket should be fine. As long as the programs handles those functions and performs well. Opening too many sockets will only lead to more doors being opened. You can have many handlers handling different functionalities and have a logical separation in your code.